# PHP: array_push() solo me muestra el primer elemento de un JSON

Tags: php, json

tengo un json que me devuelve un objeto con varios elementos y cada elemento tiene muchos atributos que no necesito, solo necesito unos cuantos. Este código lo pongo dentro de una funcion y despues llamare donde lo necesito.

El problema es que solo me devuelve el primer elemento :S

Codigo

```
function getRoster(){
    $url = "http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.roster_all.bam?team_id=532";
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $jsonArray = array();
    foreach($data['roster_all']['queryResults']['row']  as $i){
            $jsonArrayItem = array();
            $jsonArrayItem['id']                = $i['player_id'];
            $jsonArrayItem['nombre']            = $i['name_display_first_last'];
            $jsonArrayItem['posicion']          = $i['position'];
            $jsonArrayItem['estado']            = $i['status_short'];
            $jsonArrayItem['numero']            = $i['jersey_number'];
            $jsonArrayItem['batea']             = $i['bats'];
            $jsonArrayItem['lanza']             = $i['throws'];
            $jsonArrayItem['fecha_nacimiento']  = $i['birth_date'];
            $jsonArrayItem['lugar_nacimiento']  = $i['birth_place'];
            $jsonArrayItem['fecha_debut']       = $i['start_date'];

        array_push($jsonArray, $jsonArrayItem);
        return json_encode($jsonArray);
    }
}

echo getRoster();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que poner esto fuera del bucle:

```
    return json_encode($jsonArray);
```

Al ponerlo dentro, el bucle se corta en la primera iteracción al encontrar el `return`.

Si lo pones así debería funcionar:

```
function getRoster(){
    $url = "http://lookup-service-prod.mlb.com/json/named.roster_all.bam?team_id=532";
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
    $jsonArray = array();
    foreach($data['roster_all']['queryResults']['row']  as $i){
            $jsonArrayItem = array();
            $jsonArrayItem['id']                = $i['player_id'];
            $jsonArrayItem['nombre']            = $i['name_display_first_last'];
            $jsonArrayItem['posicion']          = $i['position'];
            $jsonArrayItem['estado']            = $i['status_short'];
            $jsonArrayItem['numero']            = $i['jersey_number'];
            $jsonArrayItem['batea']             = $i['bats'];
            $jsonArrayItem['lanza']             = $i['throws'];
            $jsonArrayItem['fecha_nacimiento']  = $i['birth_date'];
            $jsonArrayItem['lugar_nacimiento']  = $i['birth_place'];
            $jsonArrayItem['fecha_debut']       = $i['start_date'];

        array_push($jsonArray, $jsonArrayItem);
    }
    #Fuera del bucle 
    return json_encode($jsonArray);
}

echo getRoster();
```

Comment: Vaya era eso, moví todo el codigo pero no se me ocurrió, ya que antes lo había hecho pero con un select a una tabla de mysql, con un while en lugar de foreach y el json_encode($jsonArray) lo mantenía dentro del while, en fin GRACIAS!